# let $X$ be a standard Gaussian random variable. Show that $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

i'm trying to understand a proof of the following statement:

> let $X$ be a standard Gaussian random variable. Show that $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous.

I'll write down the proof in such a way that i can show you where i have troubles.

*Proof*:

We assume that $V:=(X,X)$ is absolutely continuous, meaning  that there exists a map $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ which is Lebesgue measurable and such that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} f d\lambda^2=1$, where $\lambda^2$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Then for all Borel measurable maps $h:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, we have
$$\Bbb{E}[h(X,X)]=\Bbb{E}[V] \overset{by def}{=} \int_{\Omega}h(V)d\Bbb{P}\overset{(1)}{=}\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)d\Bbb{P}_V(x,y) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)f(x,y)d\lambda^2(x,y).$$

On the other hand we have
$$\Bbb{E}[h(X,X)]\overset{bydef}{=}\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)d\Bbb{P}\overset{(2)}{=}\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x,x)d\Bbb{P}_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x,x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}d\lambda(x)$$

Now choose $h:\Bbb{1}_A(x,y)$, where $A:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2:x=y\}$. By the first relation we have:
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)f(x,y)d\lambda^2(x,y)=0$$
Since the measure of a line is $0$ with respect to $\lambda^2$. By the second relation we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x,x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1$$

Since we reached a contradiction we can deduce that $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous.

What i don't understand are the equalities $(1),(2)$ What is the "trick" behind the definition of $V:=(X,X)$. Why does this definition lead to the two different equalities $(1),(2)?$ Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integral representations are applications of the following: If $Y$ is a random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$
{\rm E}[u(Y)]:=\int_{\Omega} u(Y)\,\mathrm dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y)\,P_Y(\mathrm dy),\tag{1}
$$
for measurable, bounded $u$. Here $P_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$ which is the measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$$
P_Y(A)=P(Y^{-1}(A)),
$$
for Borel sets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

The first equality follows from $(1)$ with $Y=V$ and $u=h$. The second equality follows from $(1)$ with $Y=X$ and $u=h\circ g$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $g(x)=(x,x)$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! however The contradiction is clear, what is less clear is why

$$E(h(X,X))=\begin{cases}=\Bbb{E}[V] =\int_{\Omega}h(V)d\Bbb{P}=\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)d\Bbb{P}_V(x,y)\\
=\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)d\Bbb{P}=\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x,x)d\Bbb{P}_X(x)\end{cases}$$

Why do we get two different integrals? One over $\Bbb{R}^2$ and the other over $\Bbb{R}$? I mean $\int_{\Omega} h(V)dP$ is also equal $\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)$ by definition of $V$, but this is not equal to $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)d\Bbb{P}_V(x,y)$

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my answer tries to explain?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i have explained myself bad or i did not understand completely your answer. I understand the second equality, that is i understand that if you define $g(x)=(x,x)$ then 
$$\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)dP = \int_{\Omega}h(g(X))dP \overset{(1)}{=}  \int_{\Bbb{R}}h(g(x))dP_X$$
what i don't understand is why, when we define $V:=(X,X)$ we like "forget" that $V$ is equal to $(X,X)$. We have $\int_{\Omega}h(V)dP$, we use $(1)$ and we get $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} h(x,y)dP_V$. where the second step suggests me that $V$ is considered as any random vector on $\Bbb{R}^2$. Do we have to think that $V$ is on R^2

Comment: Sorry i need to continue here because i don't have any characters left. My doubt is: Are we allowed to treat $V$ as any random vector on $\Bbb{R}^2$ and then get the contraddiction? if yes why? why can we forget that $V$ is equal to $(X,X)$ and suppose that $V$ is equal to $(X,Y)$ for example?

Comment: $V=(X,X)$ _is_ a random variable (or vector) with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and nothing else. Applying $(1)$ directly yields ${\rm E}[h(V)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} h(v)\,P_V(\mathrm dv)$ and if we assume that $V$ has density $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ then this is also $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} h(v)f(v)\,\lambda_2(\mathrm dv)$. You say "and suppose that $V$ is equal to $(X,Y)$". We don't suppose that (there isn't even a $Y$ anywhere). We simply write $v=(x,y)$. Alternatively, you could write $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and obtain $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} h(v_1,v_2)f(v_1,v_2)\,\lambda_2(\mathrm dv_1,\mathrm dv_2)$.

Comment: I have revised my answer to hopefully it make this more clear.

Comment: Ah! I think i got it, when we have the integral $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} h(v)f(v)\lambda_2(dv)$ $v$ is a vector in R^2, and for this reason it has two different components. I thought that since $V$ was defined as $(X,X)$ then we should have had $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} h(v)f(v)\lambda_2(dv) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,x)f(x,x)\lambda_2$ But is only the random variable $V$ that is defined as $(X,X)$ and when we have $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} h(v)f(v)\lambda_2(dv)$, $v$ is no longer equal $(x,x)$ but is equal to any vector on $\Bbb{R}^2$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Exactly @Ale! ${}$

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help and your time! Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

Define $\triangle=\left\{ \left(x,x\right)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\right\} $
here.

Suppose that $f\left(x,y\right)$ serves as PDF here.

Then we get the contradiction: $$1=P\left\{ \left(X,X\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\right\} =P\left\{ \left(X,X\right)\in\triangle\right\} =\int_{\triangle}fd\lambda=0$$
The last equality as a consequence of $\lambda\left(\triangle\right)=0$.

This shows that there is no PDF, i.e. that the distribution of $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous.

The fact that $X$ is standard Gaussian plays no part in this.

---

**addendum**

In my view it is handsome to write $\mu\left(f\right)$ for integral $\int fd\mu$.

In fact $\mu$ is
no longer looked at as a function on measurable sets but as a function
(with nice properties) on integrable functions. The original measure of set $A$ can be found back as $\mu\left(1_A\right)$.

Defining $\delta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$
by $x\mapsto\left(x,x\right)$ we come to $V=\delta\circ X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Here: $$P_{V}\left(h\right)=P\left(h\circ V\right)=P\left(h\circ\delta\circ X\right)=P_{X}\left(h\circ\delta\right)$$
$P$ denotes the original probability measure on $\Omega$ and $P_{V}$
and $P_{X}$ are induced measures on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}$
respectively.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! however The contradiction is clear, what is less clear is why

$$E(h(X,X))=\begin{cases}=\Bbb{E}[V] =\int_{\Omega}h(V)d\Bbb{P}=\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)d\Bbb{P}_V(x,y)\\
=\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)d\Bbb{P}=\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x,x)d\Bbb{P}_X(x)\end{cases}$$

Why do we get two different integrals? One over $\Bbb{R}^2$ and the other over $\Bbb{R}$? I mean $\int_{\Omega} h(V)dP$ is also equal $\int_{\Omega}h(X,X)$ by definition of $V$, but this is not equal to $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}h(x,y)d\Bbb{P}_V(x,y)$

Comment: Define $\delta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by $x\mapsto\left(x,x\right)$.
Then $V=\delta\circ X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Writing $\mu\left(f\right)$
instead of $\int fd\mu$ where $f$ is an measurable and integrable
function and $\mu$ a measure, we have $P_{V}\left(h\right)=P\left(h\circ V\right)=P\left(h\circ\delta\circ X\right)=P_{X}\left(h\circ\delta\right)$.
Here $P_{V}\left(h\right)$ stands for $\int h\left(x,y\right)dP_{V}\left(x,y\right)$
and $P_{X}\left(h\circ\delta\right)$ stands for $\int h\left(x,x\right)P_{X}\left(dx\right)$. So the integrals are equal.